# The relative homology group $H_{1}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{Q})$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

This problem is an extract of Hatcher's book.

> Show that for the subspace $\mathbb{Q}\subset \mathbb{R}$, the relative homology group $H_{1}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{Q})$ is free abelian and find a basis.

I have no idea (edit : for the first part of the question, I think I have to use the long exact sequence...). Thank you for help !

Comment: Write down the long exact sequence of the pair (\mathbb{R},\mathbb{Q}). What does it tell you about $H_1(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{Q})$?

Comment: I have $H_{1}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{Q})\rightarrow H_{0}(\mathbb{Q})\rightarrow H_{0}(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow H_{0}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{Q})$, and...

Comment: Put one more term to the left, it's $H_1(\mathbb{R})$. Now do you know anything about $H_1(\mathbb{R})$ and $H_0(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: Ok, thank you... Hum, $H_{0}(\mathbb{R})=\mathbb{Z}$ ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$\require{cancel} \newcommand\R{\mathbb{R}} \newcommand\Q{\mathbb{Q}} \newcommand\Z{\mathbb{Z}}$
Write down the long exact sequence in homology:
$$\cancel{H_1(\R)} \to H_1(\R,\Q) \to H_0(\Q) \to H_0(\R)$$
The space $\R$ is contractible so $H_0(\R) = \Z$ and $H_1(\R) = 0$. It's known that $H_0$ counts path components, and each point of $\Q$ is its own path component (the only continuous maps $[0,1] \to \Q$ are constant maps). So you get:
$$H_0(\Q) = \bigoplus_{x \in \Q} \mathbb{Z}_x$$
where each $\Z_x$ is a copy of $\Z$. The map $H_0(\Q) \to H_0(\R)$ sends each $1_x \in \Z_x$ to $1 \in H_0(\R) \cong \Z$.

Because of the long exact sequence, $H_1(\R,\Q)$ is the kernel of this map. If you take some chosen base point $x_0 \in \Q$ (for example $x_0 = 0$), then this kernel is the subgroup of $H_0(\Q)$ generated by the $1_x - 1_{x_0}$ for $x \in \Q$. More than that, this set is a basis of $H_1(\R,\Q)$ as an abelian group (so it's free, in general a subgroup of a free abelian group is free abelian).

Comment: How do $0$-chains generate $H_1(\mathbb R, \mathbb Q)$?

Comment: @Wolfgang The long exact sequence tells you that $H_1(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{Q})$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $H_0(\mathbb{Q})$.

Comment: Right. But don't we have to use that isomorphism to find the generators of $H_1(\mathbb R, \mathbb Q)$, as it doesn't make sense to say a $0$-chains generate a group which comprises of $1$-chains?

Comment: @Wolfgang Yes. What do you want me to say?

Comment: I guess I'm confused as to how to get the actual $1$-chains which generate $H_1(\mathbb R, \mathbb Q)$. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: @Wolfgang The generator of $H_1(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{Q})$ corresponding to $1_x \in H_0(\mathbb{Q})$ (for $x \in \mathbb{Q})$ is simply the segment $[0,x]$.

Comment: Consider $2(1_x - 1_{x_0})-(1_y -1_{x_0})$ where $x, y \in \mathbb Q$. This element is not in the kernel of $H_0(\mathbb Q) \to H_0(\mathbb R)$. So, how is $1_x-1_{x_0}$ a generator for the kernel?

Comment: @Wolfgang What do you mean, it's not in the kernel? In $H_0(\mathbb{R})$, you have $1_x = 1_{x_0} = 1_y$.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps this is an easier way of seeing this, in a very similar way to Najib's answer.

Instead of using the LES on homology, use the LES on *reduced* homology:

$$H_1(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow H_1(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{Q}) \rightarrow \widetilde{H_0}(\mathbb{Q}) \rightarrow \widetilde{H_0}(\mathbb{R})$$

Note that, since $\mathbb{R}$ is contractible, $\widetilde{H_0}(\mathbb{R}) = 0$ and $H_1(\mathbb{R}) = 0$. We also know that $\widetilde{H_0}(\mathbb{Q}) \cong \bigoplus\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z}$.

So we have the following exact sequence:

$$0 \rightarrow H_1(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{Q}) \rightarrow \bigoplus\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow 0$$

By exactness, it follows that $H_1(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{Q}) \cong \bigoplus\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z}$, so $H_1(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{Q})$ is a free abelian group on countably infinitely many generators.